# Magento 2.3 - Unpredictable Error - Shipping Matrix Rate calculation partially working error

Tags: shipping-methods, magento2.3.4

I am using **webshop shipping matrix rate**, if **cart value below 50** then only showing shipping methods, **above 50 not shown**, how to solve this error?

**Note:** There is no relevant log error

Database : https://snipboard.io/linb4Y.jpg

Comment: In your table rate carrier model. In below condition return false; So it wont show the shipping method.

if (!empty($rate) && $rate['price'] >= 0) {
            if ($request->getPackageQty() == $freeQty) {
               return false;

Comment: Where i can update?

Comment: There must be a Matrixrate.php carrier model available in your extension there you can find the condition i provided above. You need to return false from that condition.